# How to center components of grid in MUI?

Tags: css, material-ui

I am very new to MUI and I am working with the grid at the moment.

```
<Grid className={classes.grid} container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
                    {data.data.map((item, index) => {
                        return (
                            <Grid container className={classes.gridChild} item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
                                <Card name={item.name} genre={item.genre} rating={item.rating} img={item.img} key={item.id} lang={item.lang} />
                            </Grid>
                            )
                    })}
                </Grid>
```

Now the cards that are being shown here are not exactly centered, I get that they will have spaces in between them but why are they not centered the same as the illustrations in the documentation?

I have tried properties such as `justifyContent` and `alignItems`, the issue with it is that it centers things, yes, but the spacing still remains. When I say spacing, it is the property of grid `spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }}`. This space doesn't go away hence disturbs the centering.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: you just need to add `justifyContent="center"` in <Grid> component as MUI mentioned in their [documentation](https://mui.com/components/grid/#interactive).   you can also use `alignItems="center"` along with `justifyContent="center"` if you need.

Comment: I have tried it, It doesn't give me desired results.

Comment: [Grid MUI Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/grid-mui-6fuqmp?file=/src/index.js)   Check this example of it, maybe you get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Grid layout uses flex module of css. You can use below properties to make it center.
justifyContent="center"
alignItems="center"

Comment: The thing is, I tried doing it but it justifies the div itself and not its content, there is still some space due to `spacing={9}` property, which doesn't make sense.